# How can I show 1/0 if a client buy or not in a month in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an error on measure m-test2 on the filter
Can you help me?[image: sampledata]

Comment: Hi, can you outline what you are trying to achieve and the expected results

Comment: Converting your boolean column to integer format should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't answer yor question, but you can't use the True/Fales line in a `CALCULATE` like that. It's a built in thing (that's the error message you're getting). There are two ways of getting around it.

Either create a variable:

```
m-test2 = 
var currentDate = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()); MONTH(TODAY()); 31)

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Test[BOLEAN]);
    Test[Datalink] > currentDate
)
```

Or put the T/F argument inside a filter-function:

```
m-test-2 = 

CALCULATE(
    SUM(Test[BOOLEAN]);
    FILTER(
        Test;
        Test[Datalink] > DATE( YEAR(TODAY()); MONTH(TODAY()); 31)
    )
)
```